# How to change "Node shape to Bubble" & change "Child gap" using script?

Tags: javascript, groovy, freeplane

In Freeplane, how do I change "Node shape to Bubble" and change "Child gap" using a Groovy script?

I have tried

```js
node.style.topic = "Bubble"
```

and

```js
node.childgap = "5 pt"
```

But neither works.

Comment: I strongly doubt, that this the [groovy] you tagged here.

Comment: Freeplane actually has a Groovy scripting API, so [groovy] is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Freeplane hasn't included node shapes into the (Groovy) scripting API yet. But you can use the lower level Java API for now (be warned that that might break at some point of time):

```
import org.freeplane.features.nodestyle.NodeStyleModel
import org.freeplane.core.ui.LengthUnits
import org.freeplane.core.util.Quantity

NodeStyleModel.setShape(node.delegate, "bubble")
NodeStyleModel.setShapeVerticalMargin(node.delegate, new Quantity(5, LengthUnits.px))
NodeStyleModel.setShapeHorizontalMargin(node.delegate, new Quantity(15, LengthUnits.px))

node.text = String.valueOf(NodeStyleModel.getShape(node.delegate))
```

Please add a feature request to Freeplane's bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solves to an extend.